# minimize the amount of words in a python string

Tags: python, string

i am building a discord bot that searches wikipedia pages, the only problem is when i am trying to minimize the amount of words in the summary, the bot becomes slow, the method i used for this code is not fast for the bot, here is the code that i am using:

```
minimize = search_summary.split(' ')
if len(minimize) > 200:
    print("minimizing")
    minimize = minimize[:199]
    message = ' '.join(minimize)
```

is there another way to cut the words to a max of 200 in the most efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would produce much less overhead if you scanned the string for the place to split and than just did one split.
Here is a version with a regex:

```
import re

def first_n_words(text, n):
    assert n > 0
    match = re.search(r"(\S+\s){%s}\S+" % (n - 1), text)
    if not match:
        return text
    else:
        return text[match.span()[0]: match.span()[1]]

s = "abc def\nghi jkl m no"
max_words = 2

print("============")
print(first_n_words(s, 1))
print("============")
print(first_n_words(s, 2))
print("============")
print(first_n_words(s, 3))
print("============")
print(first_n_words(s, 4))
```

Note that it naively assumes `n > 0`.

Still better would be if you could already limit the input, i.e. not load the whole wikipedia article but just up to n characters.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your variant may be one of efficient. I make some benchmarks with Timench. If you have long strings regex small faster

Functions:
`crop_string_0` - Vajra Budiono, `crop_string_1` and `crop_string_2` are my variants with lists operations and regex, `first_n_words` by Chr1s

```
def crop_string_0(text: str, count: int):
    minimize = text.split(' ')
    if len(minimize) > count:
        minimize = minimize[:count-1]
    return ' '.join(minimize)


def crop_string_1(text: str, count: int):
    return ' '.join(text.split(' ')[:count-1])


def crop_string_2(text: str, count):
    return re.search('^((\S+\s?){0,%s})' % count, text).group(1)


def first_n_words(text, n):
    assert n > 0
    match = re.search(r"(\S+\s){%s}\S+" % (n - 1), text)
    if not match:
        return text
    else:
        return text[match.span()[0]: match.span()[1]]
```

I  run all of it twice: for text longer than 200 words and less than 100 words.

Log for longer than 200 words case:

```
Case: crop_string_0
---
Function: crop_string_0
Total time = 0.876876 sec
Best loop time = 2.8308e-05 sec
Average loop time = 8.76876e-05 sec
Repeats = 10000

Case: crop_string_1
---
Function: crop_string_1
Total time = 0.77493 sec
Best loop time = 2.8287e-05 sec
Average loop time = 7.7493e-05 sec
Repeats = 10000

Case: crop_string_2
---
Function: crop_string_2
Total time = 0.729405 sec
Best loop time = 6.6183e-05 sec
Average loop time = 7.29405e-05 sec
Repeats = 10000

Case: first_n_words
---
Function: first_n_words
Total time = 0.63622 sec
Best loop time = 1.1667e-05 sec
Average loop time = 6.3622e-05 sec
Repeats = 10000
```

And log for short text (100 words):

```
Case: crop_string_0
---
Function: crop_string_0
Total time = 0.0114764 sec
Best loop time = 1.0763e-05 sec
Average loop time = 1.14764e-05 sec
Repeats = 1000

Case: crop_string_1
---
Function: crop_string_1
Total time = 0.0235537 sec
Best loop time = 1.109e-05 sec
Average loop time = 2.35537e-05 sec
Repeats = 1000

Case: crop_string_2
---
Function: crop_string_2
Total time = 0.0478017 sec
Best loop time = 7.974e-06 sec
Average loop time = 4.78017e-05 sec
Repeats = 1000

Case: first_n_words
---
Function: first_n_words
Total time = 3.51248 sec
Best loop time = 0.00064735 sec
Average loop time = 0.00351248 sec
Repeats = 1000
```

github link for benchmark code: https://github.com/ndrwpvlv/timench/blob/main/examples/example_4.py

Comment: thx for the documentation andy, really appreciate some news about the algorithm i'm using